# Same working model in Keras not being improved in Pytorch

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I'm converting a basic LSTM many-to-one architecture to predict the next single element in a sequence, written in Keras to Pytorch. NN architecture is the following (whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/Skuldur/Classical-Piano-Composer/blob/master/lstm.py)):

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
    512,
    input_shape=(network_input.shape[1], network_input.shape[2]),
    return_sequences=True
))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(512))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(n_vocab))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Running both models with the same data (yes, I've explicitly checked that), both start with a loss value ~ 4, but after 100 epochs or so, Keras already reached a loss ~ 0.02, which gives the desired results.

However, Pytorch model is stuck around ~ 3.4 after 20 epochs. I've tried many things:

- Play with LR: It explodes when LR is too high, so this means that at least parameters are being updated.
- Different optimizers, SGD, Adam, RMSprop, but same results with all.
- Swap between `.view[]`, `.squeeze_` and indexing when accessing last sequence element.
- Add, remove and modify non-linear activation functions and dropout.
- Remove manual initialization for x_0 and h_0.

Here is the code for my model:

```py
class NNP_RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NNP_RNN, self).__init__()
        self.lstm_1 = nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=512, batch_first=True)
        self.lstm_2 = nn.LSTM(input_size=512, hidden_size=512, batch_first=True)
        self.lstm_3 = nn.LSTM(input_size=512, hidden_size=512, batch_first=True)

        self.dense_1 = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256)
        self.dense_2 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=58)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        h_0 = NNP_RNN.init_hidden((1, batch_size, 512))
        c_0 = NNP_RNN.init_hidden((1, batch_size, 512))

        x, _ = self.lstm_1(x, (h_0, c_0))
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.3)

        x, _ = self.lstm_2(x, (h_0, c_0))
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.2)

        _, (x, _) = self.lstm_3(x, (h_0, c_0))
        x = x.squeeze_(0)

        x = self.dense_1(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.1)

        x = self.dense_2(x)

        return x

    @staticmethod
    def init_hidden(dims):
        return torch.zeros(dims, device=device)
```

And the training process:

```py
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, factor=0.2, verbose=True, patience=5)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_corrects = 0
    for features, labels in tqdm(data, ncols=800):
        features = features.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        batch_size = features.size(0)
        output = model(features)

        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        corrects = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)
        corrects = torch.eq(corrects, labels).sum().item()
        epoch_corrects += corrects

        epoch_loss += loss.clone() * batch_size

    epoch_loss /= len(data.dataset)
    epoch_corrects /= len(data.dataset)
    print(f'Loss epoch #{epoch} = {epoch_loss:.10f}, Accuracy = {epoch_corrects}')

    scheduler.step(epoch_loss)
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with the scheduler? Or even removing it? I didn’t see a scheduler (or something similar) in the Keras code, but may have just missed it.

Comment: The original one hasn't one, but when I copy-pasted in my notebook I added one (with same parameters) and helped to converge faster when gets a bit stuck in some high epochs. In Pytorch model it just keeps decreasing every 5 epochs (patience) as the loss doesn't decrease at all...

Comment: Do the forward pass results much on a small input?

Comment: Yes, quite small, the output results in something like this:
tensor([[-0.0668, -0.0005,  0.0391,  ...,  0.0060,  0.0247, -0.0221],
        [-0.0672, -0.0009,  0.0490,  ...,  0.0020,  0.0334, -0.0251],
        ...
        [-0.0637,  0.0011,  0.0462,  ...,  0.0169,  0.0228, -0.0252]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)